# Federal Limitations on Model Rocketry in India

Tags: rockets, launch, law, model-rocketry, india

I am hoping to find information on the rules regarding model rocket launches in India.  How high can I fly? How heavy can a custom rocket be?  Can I legally make and fly custom engines/motors?

Comment: Assuming that the edit is correct and that the question is about model rockets, I've retracted my close vote.